# plot displayed in the viewer in Rstudio but not in the webbrowser in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, r-markdown

I am doing a dashboard in R with flexdashboard , and I am using shiny to have an interactive dashboard. The problem is the following :
I have one plot that is not displayed in the browser but which appears in the Rstudio viewer and get updated each time I use my selectInput button. I don't understand why it doesn't work in my browser

```
    g<-renderPlot({

    data <- products[category == input$Cat]
    data<-data[order(-n_sold)][1:10]        
    data<-data[,c("link","n_sold")]
    nprods <- 10



    highchart() %>%
    hc_chart(type = "bar") %>%
    hc_xAxis(categories =data$link) %>%
    hc_add_series(name ="number sold",data = data$n_sold)%>%
    hc_add_theme(thm)%>%
    hc_plotOptions(
    series = list(
    cursor = "pointer",
    point = list(
      events = list(
        click = JS( "function () { location.href = this.category; }")
        )
      )
    )
  ) 


    })
```

Answer (score 0):

R and Shiny are different environments, as your issue demonstrates. I would advise you to debug this error in a basic, stepwise fashion. Change or remove one single part of your code and then check whether the app works online. This will allow you to find what part(s) of your code is causing the error, and to gradually fix the code.

Comment: I have used renderHighchart() instead of renderPlot() but this work only once in Rstudio webbrowser interface, if I rerun the pg again the plot won't appears and moreover it doesn't work in chrome browser